# Find $\int{\sqrt[5]{\frac{x}{x+1}}\frac{1}{x^3}}\>dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How to integrate

$$\int{\sqrt[5]{\frac{x}{x+1}}\>\frac{1}{x^3}}\>dx$$

---

My work:

$$ \sqrt[5]{\frac{x}{x+1}}=t$$

$$t^5=\frac{x}{x+1}$$

$$5t^4dt=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

But here, I don't know how to get $\frac{1}{x^3}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is more desirable to utilize the substitution $t=\sqrt[5]\frac{1+x}x$, instead. As a result, $\frac1x=t^5-1$,
$\frac{dx}{x^3}= -\frac{5t^4}{x}dt= 5(t^4-t^9)dt
$
and

$$\int{\sqrt[5]{\frac{x}{x+1}}\frac{1}{x^3}}dx
=5\int(t^3-t^8)dt= \frac54t^4 - \frac59t^9+C
$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=\frac{x}{x+1}, dt=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx, x=\frac{t}{1-t}$ (why?) so $x+1=\frac{1}{1-t}$ and we have

$$\int{\sqrt[5]{\frac{x}{x+1}}\frac{dx}{x^3}}=\int \frac{t^{\frac{1}{5}}}{(1-t)^2}\frac{(1-t)^3}{t^3}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{1-t}{t^{\frac{14}{5}}}dt=\int t^{-\frac{14}{5}}dt-\int t^{-\frac{9}{5}}dt=...$$

Answer (score 0):

$t^5=\frac{x}{x+1} \Rightarrow xt^5+t^5=x \Rightarrow x=\frac{t^5}{1-t^5}$

$5t^4 dt = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} dx \Rightarrow dx=5t^4 (x+1)^2 dt$

$x+1=\frac{t^5}{1-t^5}+1=\frac{1}{1-t^5}$

$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^3}=\frac{(1-t^5)^{-2}}{t^{15}(1-t^5)^{-3}}=\frac{1-t^5}{t^{15}}$

$\frac{t dx}{x^3}=\frac{5t^4 (x+1)^2}{x^3} dt=\frac{5 (1-t^5)}{t^{11}} dt=(5 t^{-11}-5t^{-6})dt$